# can't login in register/login system nodejs JWT MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm new in backend and I'm trying to create a simple register/login system. I registered successfully a user in DB and when
I tried to login by this user I get  {msg: "incorrect username"}
did I do something wrong?

that's the login route

```
router.post('/login',  (req, res, next)=>{
  db.query(`select * from users where user_name = ${db.escape(req.body.user_name)};`,
    (err, result)=> {
      // ? user does not exist
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({msg:err})
        
      }
      if (!result.length) {
        return res.status(401).send({msg: "incorrect username"})
      }

      // ? check pass and compare it 

      bcrypt.compare(
        req.body.password, result[0]['password'], (bErr, bResult)=>{
          // ? wrong pass 
          if (bErr) {
            throw bErr 
            return res.status(401).send({msg:"pass incorrect"})
          }

          if (bResult) {
            const token = jwt.sign({
              user_name: result[0].user_name,
              id: result[0].id
            },
            'SECRETKEY', {expiresIn: '7d'})


            db.query(
              `UPDATE users SET last_login = now() WHERE id = '${result[0].id}'`);

            return res.status(200).send({
              msg: 'Logged in!',
              token,
              user: result[0] });
          }

          return res.status(401).send({ msg: 'Username or password is incorrect!!!!'});

          
        }
        
      )

    }
  )
})
```

Comment: Maybe the username is incorrect.

Comment: Check (e.g with `console.log`) if `db.escape(req.body.user_name)` really contains what you think.

Comment: Please add the html form to give a proof of the fields posted.